# PHP: Remove http://, http://www, https://, https:// from String and get the Domain name and TLD

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to create a function in `PHP` that removes all inputs like

```
http://
https://
http://www.
https://www.
http://xyz.
```

from a given domain name like

```
example.com
```

and returns an array like this:

```
'name' => 'example'
'tld' => 'com'
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Are there any `.co.uk` TLDs?

Comment: You mean like [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)?

Comment: Yes, it should be able to handle co.uk aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex:

```
(?:^|\s)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+(?=\.).)?(?<name>.*).(?<tld>(?<=\.)\w+)
```

See demo at https://regex101.com/r/lI2lB4/2

If you input is

```
www.google.com
mail.yahoo.com.in
http://microsoft.com
http://www.google.com
http://mail.yahoo.co.uk
```

Captured content will be:

```
MATCH 1
name       = `google`
tld        = `com`

MATCH 2
name       = `yahoo.com`
tld        = `in`

MATCH 3
name       = `microsoft`
tld        = `com`

MATCH 4
name       = `google`
tld        = `com`

MATCH 5
name       = `yahoo.co`
tld        = `uk`
```

Comment: Hello,

thanks a lot. Unfortunately

`preg_match('(?:^|\s)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+(?=\.).)?(?<name>.*).(?<tld>(?<=\.)\w+)', $domain, $matches);` does not work.

I'm getting `Unknown modifier '(' in <b>/var/www`.

Comment: Try `preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);` see code generated at demo link I pasted in post.

Comment: Okay, works. I'm a fool and forgot the limiters :D Your code seems to work, I will do some test-cases :-)

Comment: Works fine. Is there a possibility to get "co" and "uk" or "de" and "vu" in separate array-elements?

Comment: Indeed it's possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How could I do that?

Comment: @B3none what is expected output?

Comment: @Saleem, currently returns `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => https://www.warwick-castle.co.uk [name] => warwick-castle.co [1] => warwick-castle.co [tld] => uk [2] => uk ) )`.

Comment: Again, question is same.  What output do you expect? see https://regex101.com/r/lI2lB4/5

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to remove *protocol*, *www* or even *subdomain*, All you need is extracting *name* and *tdl* from the URL. So try this:

**RegEx solution:**

```
<?php

$url  = 'https://www.example.com#anchor';
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);  // www.example.com
preg_match('/(\w+)\.(\w+)$/', $host, $matches);
$array_result = array ( "name" => $matches[1],
                        "tld"  => $matches[2] );
print_r($array_result);
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/0aEgu)

---

**Without RegEx:**

```
<?php

$url  = 'https://www.example.com#anchor';
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);  // www.example.com
$host_names = explode(".", $host);
$array_result = array ( "name" => $host_names[count($host_names)-2],
                        "tld"  =>  $host_names[count($host_names)-1] );
print_r($array_result);
```

#### [Online Demo](https://3v4l.org/XFThK)

---

```
/*
 Output:
 *    Array
 *    (
 *        [name] => example
 *        [tld] => com
 *    ) 
*/
```

Comment: Your solution without regex is the most flexible approach and the best it can be.

Comment: Hello... Well, I like your solution `without regex` aswell - but if I type `www.test.co.uk` the `name` will be "co" and the `tld` will be "uk"

Comment: Hello again. I just mentioned that this does work, if the domain is given without "www." aswell

Answer (score 0):

Correct way for extracting real TLD is using package that operates [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), only in this way you can correctly extract domains with two-, third-level TLDs (co.uk, a.bg, b.bg, etc.). I recomend use [TLD Extract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract).

Here is sample code:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('http://mail.yahoo.co.uk');
$result->getSubdomain(); // will return (string) 'mail'
$result->getHostname(); // will return (string) 'yahoo'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return (string) 'co.uk'
```